# OpenConnect VPN on Ubuntu 18 set up like the default of OC on Fedora Workstation? Need PA GlobalProtect VPN

Tags: vpn, openconnect

I have an older machine that is running Fedora Workstation 31. When I go into settings -> network -> Add a VPN, I see this:

[image: OpenConnect VPN - default new VPN on Fedora Workstation 31]

However, I tried to install OpenConnect VPN client for Ubuntu [with these instructions](https://grepitout.com/install-openconnect-ubuntu-vpn-client/), but this is all I see....there's no option to setup a PA GlobalProtect VPN connection:

[image: Ubuntu OC VPN - does not have option for PA GlobalProtect VPN]

**How can I setup my Ubuntu laptop so that I have the option to add a configure a GlobalProtect VPN client connection to my work?**

Comment: **They built this functionality into Ubuntu 20**

Comment: i added that in settings menu following those instructions:
https://people.eng.unimelb.edu.au/lucasjb/archive/oc_old.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot setup an GlobalProtect VPN connection inside the GUI. You have to use the terminal to setup the connection, which is actually quite easy:

Open the Terminal by <kbd>STRG</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter the following command:

```
openconnect --protocol=gp vpn.url-to-your-server.com
```

Then the you will be ask all necessary information to setup the connection. Once done, the connection is established.

To safe your time to enter manually the command, create a file on your desktop and name it `vpn.sh` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
openconnect -b --protocol=gp vpn.url-to-your-server.com
```

Safe it. Now you can just click on it, enter the details and to connection will be established automatically.

Comment: Much thanks, @f0sh! It did attempt to connect, but my work's VPN keeps prompting for a biometric response and my RSA code isn't cutting it. That's on their side though, so I've accepted this answer. :)

Comment: Got it working! I just had to press "1" to confirm biometric challenge, then press my fingerprint on my phone again in the RSA app.